# Java Instant Datetime: How to add default milliseconds during the conversion of date to Instant?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, utc

I am converting incoming date time with timezone offset into UTC time using Java Instant. If the time contains the milliseconds then I am getting the same in the converted UTC but if it is not present then I am not getting anything.

Is there any possibility to add the default way to include the milliseconds during the UTC conversion? Like if it's not present in the input then add 000 and if present then adds the same.

Following is the code I have:

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String date1 = "2020-03-04T11:00:30.123+01:00";
        System.out.println("Date 1 : " + Instant.parse(date1).toString()); //2020-03-04T10:00:30.123Z

        final String date2 = "2020-03-04T11:00:30.000+01:00";
        System.out.println("Date 2 : " + Instant.parse(date2).toString()); //2020-03-04T10:00:30Z (Expected: 2020-03-04T10:00:30.000Z)

        final String date3 = "2020-03-04T11:00:30+01:00";
        System.out.println("Date 3 : " + Instant.parse(date3).toString()); //2020-03-04T10:00:30Z (Expected: 2020-03-04T10:00:30.000Z)
    }
}
```

Following is the output:

```
Date 1 : 2020-03-04T10:00:30.123Z
Date 2 : 2020-03-04T10:00:30Z
Date 3 : 2020-03-04T10:00:30Z
```

I would like to include milliseconds always. Please let me know if there is a direct approach within Instant.

Comment: the milliseconds are always there, just not displayed if zero when using `toString()`.  Use `DateTImeFormatter` to specify your own format.

Comment: The following worked for me: `DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendInstant(3).toFormatter();` and then using this `DATE_FORMATTER.format(Instant.parse(value))`